# Getting the instance of the CurrentRow of a bindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, datarow, bindingsource

I want to get the instance of the CurrentRow of a bindingSource and assign it to a private variable.

Something like:

```
MatDataSet.KorisnikRow currentRow;    
currentRow = (MatDataSet.KorisnikRow)((DataRowView)korisnikBindingSource.Current).Row;
```

Naturally, the currentRow variable should first be created, otherwise `Object reference not set to an object` error pops up. But I don't know how or know of any workaround, so please help.

Sorry for the bad technical language.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether BindingSource is not null.

```
    if (bindingSource.Current != null)
          // your conversion
```

Comment: The bindingSource is not null. currentRow is, and that is the problem

Comment: May be you should find out what exactly is null,    var rowView = (DataRowView)korisnikBindingSource.Current;
            var row = rowView.Row;
            var currentRow = (MatDataSet.KorisnikRow) row;